# Do any stars exist apart from galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, stars

Do any stars exist apart from galaxies? Do "maverick" stars exist?

Comment: A quick google gives for example: http://news.vanderbilt.edu/2012/04/rogue-stars-intergalactic-space/. Maybe you would like to be more specific with your question? Are you interested in **formation** of stars outside of galaxies, or just if you can find them?

Comment: Hey Victor , the message `"this post does not meet our quality standards" ` is just because of missing punctuation and very short body length. Next time take care of punctuations, start a sentence with capitals and message will go away!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, as [this link](http://news.vanderbilt.edu/2012/04/rogue-stars-intergalactic-space/) (suggested by [Will](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67196/do-any-stars-exist-apart-from-galaxies#comment135457_67196)) shows.  They're expected to basically always be stars that used to be in galaxies (they formed there), but have gotten kicked out somehow.  You won't really see many stars forming between galaxies because there just isn't enough matter there to collect into stars.  Even the [ones you do find](http://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3748) will be in messy regions fairly close to other galaxies.  The most common way for the kicks to happen is if three stars (or two stars and a black hole, or something like that) get together, one couple can give an enormous boost to the third.

But the speeds you need to really fully escape are enormous.  It's easy to get kicked out of a little cluster, but you might still be stuck in the galaxy itself.  To get all the way out, you would typically need speeds of thousands of kilometers per second.  And that kind of speed is unusual for simple stars, because they tend to break up if they're hit with too much force.  We know of [one way it could happen with black holes](http://chandra.harvard.edu/blog/node/382), though.

Comment: You might also include galactic collisions under this, there is certainly enough force to throw stars out of the gravitational well of both galaxies in these instances